# Thread sleep error when I try set an ImageView

Tags: android

I get an error when a run this code, every time I set a time on sleep method I get an error and its close the application.

```
im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imag1);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso07);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is the LogCat error stack?

Comment: You should never sleep on the UI thread, in fact, sleep is nearly always bad.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the ui from a non ui thread, you can accomplish the same using a handler..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            im.setImageResource(R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso07);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thread that can touch or modify his views is the UI Thread ( MainThread) , instead you can use a `CountDownTimer` like this :

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000,5000) 
 {
      @Override
       public void onTick(long l){}

       @Override
       public void onFinish(){
          im.setImageResource(R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso07);
       };
 }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't accees UI from the background thread. You can only do via MainThread. One work around is

```
// SLEEP 5 SECONDS HERE ...
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
              // do your work here
         } 
    }, 5000);
```